# command "bash" produced invalid JSON: invalid character '\r' in string literal

Tags: sh, terraform

I have a bash script that returns an NLB cname. I want to use the returned cname as an input for my api-gateway integration.

I was deploying this code in a terraform template:

```
#!/bin/bash
nlbcname=$(aws-env terraform output nlb_arn | grep arn |  awk '$1=$1' FS="/" OFS=":" |  awk 'BEGIN{ VAR1="elb";VAR2="amazonaws.com"; FS=":"; OFS="."} {print $8,$9,VAR1,$4,VAR2}' |  sed -e 's/\./-/')
echo -n "{\"nlburl\":\"${nlbcname}\"}"
```

But I get

```
Error refreshing state: 1 error occurred:
        * data.external.nlbcname: 1 error occurred:
        * data.external.nlbcname: data.external.nlbcname: command "bash" produced invalid JSON: invalid character '\r' in string literal
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using the `dns_name` output from the [`aws_lb` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb.html)?

Comment: first resources haven't deployed, and we are using both arn and cname for the NLB

Comment: Once the resources are deployed, we will call NLB cname and integrate it to the API gateway integration through the VPC link

Comment: This feels like a very X Y problem. It might make sense to create a separate question that asks about what you're trying to achieve in a broader sense and leave this question purely for the format expected for bash based external data sources. I suspect you'll get a more useful answer out of the wider question than just focusing on this narrow issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity are you running this on Windows?

Comment: No,I'm running in Linux subsystem

Comment: Pretty sure it's that that's garbling it. Does `printf` (instead of `echo -n`) do the same?

Comment: No, same output  for "printf" also

Comment: The command returns a string terminated by `\r\n`, but the command substitution only strips the `\n`, leaving `nlbcname` to end with `\r`.

Comment: That, or your script itself contains DOS line endings, which likewise causes `nlbcname` to end with `\r`.